# Embedding HTML5 <video> element in Angular, putting its source under [src] directive

Tags: javascript, html, angular, html5-video, src

I am trying to embed a sample video using the **HTML5 video** element in my **Angular** app. When I set the source attribute, using **[src]** directive, to a string (hard-coded) URL, the video successfully gets embedded, but when I set that same URL as, for example, `_videoUrl` field either as `_videoUrl` or `this._videoUrl`, the video gets crashed like it's disabled or something. One last thing, when I inspect the video element on the browser, I see its URL resolved and correctly placed in the src attribute, which is `[src]="this._videoUrl"` in the first place, anyway, still not working, so, anyone knows what's going on here?

**NOTES:**

1. The video is a simple video hosted on *AWS S3*
2. I am using *Angular 9*
3. I am using the **[src]** in both cases, and never used the **src** attribute as is.

**Code:**

*film.compontent.html*

```
<div class="text-center col-2nd">
  <span style="display: block;">
    <video controls width="600px" height="300px">
      <source [src]="_videoUrl" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
  </span>
  <span style="display: block; font-size: 26px;">
    Official trailer
  </span>
</div>
```

*film.component.ts*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-film',
  templateUrl: './film.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./film.component.css']
})
export class FilmComponent implements OnInit {
_videoUrl;
_videoStringUrl;

constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private server: ServerService,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    private cartService: CartService
) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this._videoStringUrl = 'https://khadjiev-rk.s3.amazonaws.com/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4';
    this._videoUrl = 
         this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this._videoStringUrl);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2zsweg) use pipe for santizer to say binding is trustful

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safe'
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
 
 public transform(value: any, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
    switch (type) {
            case 'html': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
            case 'style': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
            case 'script': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
            case 'url': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
            case 'resourceUrl': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
            default: throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified: ${type}`);
        }
  }
}
```

your bind

```
[src]="_videoUrl | safe : 'url'"
```

Comment: I am not that strong in Angular, so will I need to add a new class with @Pipe? if so, how would I refer to it from that component's view?

Comment: create new ts file past code directly than in appmodule put inside declarations

Comment: I put demo in answer for u. @Khadjiev

Comment: Thank you, that worked so well, and I discovered that there was some issue that prevents the browser from rendering the video, anyway, your implementation was so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Inject the `DomSanitizer` into your component and use something like

```
get url() {
  return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this._videoUrl);
}
```

and

```
[src]="url"
```

Comment: @Khadjiev maybe you should provide some code, makes it way easier to help :)

Comment: I'll put that in the description.

Comment: can you please check?

Comment: Code seems fine. Maybe its a parsing error of the `[src]` you could try changing it to `src="{{_videoUrl}}"`

Comment: I've tried that already, but the same result, do you think there is any browser restrictions or such a thing here?

Comment: Using function for binding is bad for performance. Not good to use